# Change camera color after every 10 sec in Unity3D c#

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine, runtime, background-color

I want to change the camera colour in unity and I know how to change it once in the script camera.backgroundColor = Color.red;

But how to change it after every 10 sec interval, is there any timer like something which can be called after certain time.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), however I would solve it with a simple condition in your `Update()` method:

```
float elapsedTime;

void Update()
{
    elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

    if (elapsedTime >= 10)
    {
        elapsedTime -= 10;
        // insert logic for changing color below:
        camera.backgroundColor = Color.red;
    }
}
```

In my opinion, this is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer,

```
Timer tm = new Timer(ChangeColor, cameraObject, 0, 1000);
    private void ChangeColor(object camera)
    {
        //camera is your camera object
        if (camera != null)
        {
            camera.backgroundColor = Color.red;
        }
    }
```

Also you can pass the color as parameter in ChangeColor method to set the desired color.

```
Timer tm = new Timer(ChangeColor, color, 0, 1000);
        private void ChangeColor(object color)
        {   
            Color backColor = color as Color;
            // camera is member variable
            if (color!= null)
            {
                camera.backgroundColor = backColor ;
            }
        }
```

or You can also pass the camera object and color both as Tuple.